# Wpf: отследить нажатие shift + mouse click

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, mvvm

У меня есть кнопка, надо чтобы она реагировала на `shift + mouseclick`. При этом надо использовать `mvvm`

Вот так не работает

```
<Button>
  <Button.InputBindings>
    <MouseBinding Command="{Binding AAA}" Gesture="Shift+LeftClick" />
  </Button.InputBindings>
</Button>
```

Может есть другие способы ?

Answer (score 2):

Надо так

```
<MouseBinding Command="{Binding AAA}" MouseAction="LeftClick" Gesture="Shift+LeftClick"/>
```